# How can I union 2 tables in PHP & MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to do 'union all' 2 tables. Because of this, I wrote the code below:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM news WHERE site_id = '1'
                         UNION ALL
                         SELECT * FROM all_news)
                   ORDER BY date DESC";

$news = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while($new = mysqli_fetch_object($news))
{
   echo '- ' . $new->baslik . '<br>';
}
```

However, I got the error like that:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_result, boolean given in /../XAMPP/../../../index.php on line
>   19

*Line 19 is while's line...*

How can I fix it? I want to union 2 table, order by date all limit 10...

**EDIT:**

news table:

```
id | site_id | title | date (timestamp)
```

all_news table:

```
id | title | date (timestamp)
```

**EDIT:**
The problem was solved. I learned, if we want to use union or union all, our tables have to have same column number.

Comment: edit your question to show us what the schema is for the tables. Also check for errors on the query, you will see what's going on or not.

Comment: Your tables probably have different columns.  You should really be checking errors.

Comment: SELECT * FROM _____ table name is missing

Comment: @GordonLinoff That's what I was thinking also, and the reason why I posted my comment above yours.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I updated the post. BilalAhmed thanks but I think it has to be like that...

Comment: **Note:** The column names in the result-set are usually equal to the column names in the first SELECT statement in the UNION.

Comment: @CrisDenolatter Since the amount of columns is different between the two tables, you might look into using `JOIN` instead of `UNION`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: `if(!$news) { echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($con); }`

Comment: @Fred-ii- the error is: Error: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: There you have it and just as I suspected, and Gordon "after".

Comment: Basically your Query HAS FAILED, hence the BOOLEAN error. Its failed because a UNION will only work if the Column count in the 2 SELECT's is EQUAL and the DataTypes of column 1 in first SELECT == DataType of Column1 in second SELECT .. etc etc

Comment: If I will add site_id column to all_news but site_id columns will be empty. Is it okay?

Comment: It is working! Thanks all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To union these 2 tables you will have to add an extra dummy column to the Query of the shorter table so the rules of UNION are met.

**You dont need to add a real column to the schema for that table!**

So if the tables are

News table:

```
id | site_id | title | date (timestamp)
```

all_news table:

```
id | title | date (timestamp)
```

Then the query can be written like this

```
SELECT id, site_id, title, date FROM news WHERE site_id = '1'
UNION ALL
SELECT id, 0, title, date FROM all_news
```

Note I added a dummy column to the select list of the `all_news` table so that the column count and the datatypes of each column match each other.

You can use any number you like other than `0`, so pick one that identifies this as data you dont want to process, or it can be used to identify the rows from `all_news` by setting a specific value.

Note: I assumed `site_id` was an integer, if its a text then use `'0'` for example or `'IGNORE ME'`.